# Implementing Firebase App Check Play Integrity inside Android project

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I need info regarding implementation of Play Integrity in Android app. My app has Firebase database. We have followed this link regarding implementing Play Integrity

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider?authuser=1&hl=en

So I have

1. added library for Play Integrity in Android project
2. enabled Play Integrity in Google cloud console
3. enabled Play Integrity in Google play console
4. enabled Play integrity inside Firebase
5. added this call in Android that initializes Play integrity

```
Firebase.initialize(context = this)
var firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()
firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
    PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
)
```

It seems that we have done everything necessary. However, I’m not sure how to check if this works?
Does anyone has some suggestion or how do you guys know that PlayIntegrity works?

Comment: check out this https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/debug-provider?authuser=1